# Christmas LED dimming circuit with potentiometer

Tags: led, mosfet, potentiometer, dimmer, dimming

I need help.

I would like to dim LEDS of a Christmas tree with a potentiometer.
Here is my electric diagram. (Please note I'm a beginner in electronics.)

[image]

I don't know how to choose a good value for the potentiometer. Is my diagram correct?

I noticed that by adding a resistance in series on the postive side of the out powering cable I manage to lower the brightness of the tree, the goal of the project is to be able to adjust the brightness with the potentiometer.

Here is a picture of the power supply.

[image]

The Christmas tree 31V P=3.6W

[image]

Comment: I think this isn't going to work properly, the power supply looks to me like it outputs a **constant current**. If you place a resistor in series with the output, the power supply will simply output a higher voltage to make the current the same again and your LEDs will burn as bright as they used to. If you do manage to dim the LEDs then you're hitting the maximum output voltage of the power adapter and in the long run, that might damage it because they're not designed to operate like that.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you for your message,
Do you have any idea how I could reduce the brightness LEDs with an other safe way?

Comment: There is no "safe" way. These products are simply not designed to be dimmed. To make them dimmable a more complex power supply is needed. The one you show is a "generic and cheap" one that is used for many LED lights.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie What kind of power supply would it take to make these LEDs dimmable ?

Comment: would it work with pwm system with arduino with the original power supply or not at all?

Comment: Are you sure it is LED, not incandescent?

Comment: @user263983 I think yes and on packaging of the tree it's written LED and on the power cord I have this: https://i.imgur.com/i6k5XiG.jpg

Comment: You can buy constant current power supplies with adjustable current. Using one of those is the safest and easiest solution.

Comment: It may have some controller or connection box.  . Provide additional information or link.

Comment: @user263983 I provided all information, the leds don't have a controller, everything is in this little power supply I posted in a photo earlier.

Comment: @user1850479  Do you have some references to provide me about power supplies ?

Comment: You want a constant current power supply with dimming functionality and similar voltage range and maximum current. Thousands of options out there. Don't buy the cheapest unit on Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb here because I don't have experience with these constant current contraptions, so please let me know if this is hare-brained or not:

The supply is rated at 3.6W, 31V, 116mA.

So it seems likely the circuit is a bunch of parallel LED strips each running drawing 5mA or whatever.
[image]

So why couldn’t you just put a variable resistor across it to siphon off some of the current?
[image]

True, some drain occurs even at max setting. Make the 470 smaller if not bright enough.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply and your nice schematics ! I agree with you, I think they are parallel led strips. Yes indeed, i would like to make an variable resistor between power supply out and LEDS. But i can't put an potentiometer directly because it would be instantly damaged isn't it ?  That's why i would like to do this with mosfet and pot if it's possible, i hope to be clear.

Comment: The fixed resistor is acting as a current limiter for the potentiometer. With values shown, the pot would have to dissipate as much as 500mW which, granted, is a little much for standard pots. Making the fixed resistor larger will spare the pot but limit the maximum brightness. You could optionally get full brightness back with a switch that disengages the resistor bleed. In any case, perhaps it’d be best to test this scheme with a fixed resistor of about 1K across the supply to verify it actually does work to dim the tree.

Comment: This might work but it will require some tweaking to make it work properly. I doubt that someone with limited experience in electronics can do this without burning up some components. Also, you would be "burning off" the excess power so when you dim the LEDs, the excess power is simply turned into heat. Since the total power is about 3.6 W it isn't that much but will require some attention.

Comment: Agreed, it is certainly not an "eco-friendly" design in that the same power is just dissipated elsewhere. If you can find a supply with a variable current drive that would certainly be preferable! If not, maybe skip the problematic potentiometer and use a rotary switch to select a few different dimness settings by switching in different bleed resistors. Those resistors, as well as the fixed resistor in the drawn circuit should be power resistors, not little 1/4 Watt things.

Comment: @td127 Thanks you so much for your answer!I will try with a 1 K resistor and see how it looks like.What mean an power resistor? Do you have an example please? For the moment I only have the littles resistor.

I have a question, If I would like to keep the actual power supply and have the possibility to variate the brightness thanks to a potentiometer.
Would it be possible to create a circuit something like my first schematic to do that? And put the mosfet like a variable resistor so it will dissipate the excess heat?

Comment: Power resistor = https://imgur.com/a/exHXmbh
Right ?

Comment: No, those are way too macho (10-100W). The power supply is only rated to 3.6W. With the values shown, worst case the 470 Ohm will see the full 34V across it and have to dissipate 34*34/470 = 2 Watts, so a resistor rated at 3W should be sufficient. And you can get potentiometers rated at 2 or 3 Watts too. Not expensive. Digikey or Mouser.

Comment: I think it would be hard to get fine control with a MOSFET - they tend to be used as switches, not variable resistors. If you are eager to try it out before waiting for the 2-3W resistors to arrive, you can put a few of your little resistors together. For example, five 100 ohm 1/4W resistors in series, or five 1/4W 2.5K resistors in parallel will give you 500 ohms and 1.25W dissipation.

Comment: You could make an adjustable current sink with a linear regulator or a couple of transistors, controlled by a potentiometer. Example (replace the resistor with a pot and short out the load): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LM317#/media/File:LM317_1A_ConstCurrent.svg